# Display default value into ComboBox without set NAME (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, default, default-value

I have `ComboBox`:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MonthDaysList}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/>
```

Here is method to generate `MonthDaysList` data:

```
public ObservableCollection<string> MonthDaysList { get; internal set; }
public void GetMonths() {
   MonthDaysList = new ObservableCollection<string>();
   foreach (var item in MyConceptItems) {
            MonthDaysList.Add(item.DateColumn);
   }}
```

ObservableCollection & Binding are working fine, but it's not displayed default/first item into `ComobBox`:

[image]

It's possible to resolve it `without` set up Name of `ComboBox`?

Comment: Set the SelectedIndex property to 0 if you want to selected the first value? Or define a string source property in the view model and bind the SelectedItem property of the ComboBox to this one.

Comment: tried , but when Im reloaded the MonthDaysList it's not refreshed

Comment: What value do want to select?

Comment: just first......MonthDaysList is reloaded each time and working, but it's not set up default/first item into cb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a `string` source property in the view model and bind the `SelectedItem` property of the `ComboBox` to this one:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MonthDaysList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMonthDay}"/>
```

Make sure that you implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface if you intend to set the source property dynamically:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<string> _monthDaysList;
    public ObservableCollection<string> MonthDaysList
    {
        get { return _monthDaysList; }
        internal set { _monthDaysList = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }


    private string _selectedMonthDay;
    public string SelectedMonthDay
    {
        get { return _selectedMonthDay; }
        internal set { _selectedMonthDay = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public void GetMonths()
    {
        MonthDaysList = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        if (MyConceptItems != null && MyConceptItems.Any())
        {
            foreach (var item in MyConceptItems)
            {
                MonthDaysList.Add(item.DateColumn);
            }
            SelectedMonthDay = MonthDaysList[0];
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: I probably need to make a little changes inside your code @mm8 as Im using [AddINotifyPropertyChangedInterface] but thank you for tip how need to be done

Comment: My code is just an example. You may of course edit it however you want according to your requirements. This is not part of the question though.

Comment: exactly, as I'm learning so making changes inside examples are good practice for me